# Python custom modules management

Tags: python, import, module

I have a script (dump_ora_shelve.py) which retrieves the data from [shelve-storage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) by specifying the key, e.g.:

```
def get_shelve_users(field):
    import shelve
    db = shelve.open('oracle-shelve')
    for key in db:
        if key == field:
             return db[key]
    db.close()
```

The data is retrieved just fine:

```
print(get_shelve_users('db_users'))
> {'SYS': 'sysdba'}
print(get_shelve_users('oratab'))
> ['orcl:/u01/app']
```

There is another script which should do the same thing (retrieve the data with key specified) that has dump_ora_shelve imported, but the value returns is Null:

```
from before_OOP.dump_ora_shelve import get_shelve_users
print(get_shelve_users('db_users'))
> Null
print(get_shelve_users('oratab'))
> Null
```

The file being imported is located one level above from the file it is importing to.

Please note if I copy both files to the same location import and then function works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide the full pathname to `shelve.open`. Remember that inside a module, `__file__` is the path of where the source file resides. So you can use that to construct the full pathname.

Typically you will have something like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Use `os.path.join` to concatenate the directory and the filename. Note the use of `os.path.dirname` and `os.path.abspath`.

So you can say:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
shelve_db = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'oracle-shelve')
db = shelve.open('oracle-shelve')
```

This assumes that the `orache-shelve` file is in the same folder as the module in which the `get_shelve_users` function is (`dump_ora_shelve.py`).

Don't forget the `__file__`. That is what makes the whole thing tick, i.e. makes your program insulated from whatever its current directory is.

Comment: It makes sense. Would you please clarify how can I specify the absolute file to my shelve using BASE_DIR?  
I have tried to do the following:   

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('oracle-shelve')))

but it returns the location where the shelve exists and not the fill absolute path to the file itself

Comment: Have added note about important os.path functions to know.

Comment: Thanks. It looks much better. But the call of get_shelve_users('db_users') from another script still returns none, when it works from dump_ora_shelve file. 
     from before_OOP.dump_ora_shelve import get_shelve_users
     print(get_shelve_users('db_users'))
     > None

Comment: Hope you are using `__file__`

Comment: Have tried both __    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('oracle-shelve')))
__ and __    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
__   
Both returns None

Comment: it appears __print(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))__ returns the location of the project, but 'oracle-shelve' is located in the folder in the project dir. How can I specify the folder in which my current file in? This way I can do __shelve_db = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'oracle-shelve')__

Comment: You can do **shelve_db = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, sub-folder-name, 'orache_shelve')**

Answer (score 0):

When running the second script your working directory will be the directory where that script is located. That working directory is kept even when you import and use a file from a different package/directory.

So if your dump_ora_shelve.py script and shelve is located in a different  directory/package it will not open the correct file.

If you provide the full path to 'oracle-shelve' in dump_ora_shelve.py it should work.

**Update:**

In your 'dump_ora_shelve.py' file:

```
ABS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

This gives you the absoulte path of the directory of ''dump_ora_shelve.py'.  Join with name of your DB:

```
shelve_db = os.path.join(ABS_DIR, 'oracle-shelve')
```

And finally:

```
db = shelve.open(shelve_db)
```

This assumes that your 'oracle-shelve' is in the same directory as 'dump_ora_shelve.py'

Comment: Ok so I have changed __shelve.open=('shelve')__ to __shelve.open=(BASE_DIR+'\Before_OOP\oracle-shelve')__ but after it is being imported and the function is called it throws: __FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'goodpath\Before_OOP\\oracle-shelve.dat'__

Comment: In your 'dump_ora_shelve.py' file:
**ABS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(_ _file_ _))** This gives you the absoulte path of the directory of ''dump_ora_shelve.py'. 
**shelve_db = os.path.join(ABS_DIR, 'oracle-shelve')** Join with name of your DB and finally: 
**db = shelve.open(shelve_db)**

This assumes that your 'oracle-shelve' is in the same directory as 'dump_ora_shelve.py'